# Mysql help updating rows with same value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named status_t:

```
**id** **page** **status** **locked**_by
  1      0        2          0
  1      1        2          0
  1      2        2          0
  2      0        0          0
  2      1        2          0
  2      2        2          0
```

primary key is ( id, page) .

In the above example I would like to update all the 
rows that **all pages** have status = 2.

**i.e.** the query should update all the rows with id = 1 to status 3. So the table will become

```
**id** **page** **status** **locked**_by
  1      0        3          1
  1      1        3          1
  1      2        3          1
  2      0        0          0
  2      1        2          0
  2      2        2          0
```

I have tried:

```
SELECT * FROM  status_t AS t
 WHERE id IN   
 (SELECT id FROM status WHERE status = 0) LIMIT 10
```

the above query fetches the rows to be updated but I cannot do that:

```
UPDATE status_t as S1 WHERE id IN 
(SELECT id FROM status_t WHERE status = 2) 
SET S1.status = 3, S1.locked_by = 1
```

EDIT:

THE ABOVE TABLE IS JUST AN EXAMPLE.

I do not want to update WHERE id = 1 . I just want to update rows no matter the id 
that have status = 2 for the same id.
In the above example if the row with key (2, 2) had status = 2 then it should be updated.

Comment: Check my answer this will update table as you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
update status_t t
join (
    select distinct id from status_t s
    where status=2 and not exists (
        select 1 from status_t ss
        where s.id=ss.id and s.status <> ss.status
    )
) i on i.id = t.id
set t.status = 3
```

The inner query selects IDs where all values of `status` are set to `2`. It achieves this result by checking that tere are no rows with the same ID and a different status.

Here is a [demo on sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/96bac/1).

Comment: thanks. How I can also apply a limit ? 
I would like to update at most N rows

Comment: @GiorgosKomnino What should happen to the rows beyond the limit?

Comment: The limit should be divided with 3 I think. So in the above example I can only put limit 3, 6, 9 etc. If I put limit 2 then it will update only the first two rows and then the last (id=1, page=2) will not be updated

Comment: @GiorgosKomnino Would the limit on the number of different IDs work then? If you set the limit to, say, 2, then up to six rows will be updated? If that would work for you, simply add `limit 2` (3, 4, whatever) before the last closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE status_t a 
INNER JOIN (SELECT id FROM status_t WHERE STATUS = 2 GROUP BY id HAVING COUNT(*) = 3 LIMIT 1) AS b ON a.id = b.id
SET a.status = 3, a.locked_by = 1;
```

This will update data as you want for all pages have status = 2

Comment: @GiorgosKomnino using my answer you can put limit serially and it updates records as you want

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the trick:

```
UPDATE status_t 
SET status = 3, locked_by = 1 
WHERE status = 2
```

There should be no need to use a sub-query, as the WHERE should be able to be used directly in the UPDATE statement.

EDIT:

I just noticed that you only had an update against the rows with `ID = 1`, which does not match the statement 'In the above example I would like to update all the rows that all pages have status = 2.`. The rows where`id = 2`, and`status = 2` would also be updated by my query.

If you need to only update a particular id, add the following at the end of my query:

`AND id = 1`

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

```
UPDATE status_t SET status = 3, locked_by = 1 WHERE status = 2
```

And if you want to achieve this in your way :

```
UPDATE 
status_t as S1 
INNER JOIN 
(
   SELECT keyword_id 
    FROM status_t WHERE status = 2
 ) as tempStatus ON id= tempStatus.keyword_id

SET S1.status = 3, S1.locked_by = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  update status_t set staus=3 ,locked_by=1 
  where id=1
```

or

```
 update status_t set status=3 ,locked_by=1 
  where status=2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE status_t SET status = 3, S1.locked_by = 1 WHERE id = 1
```